# Including template that is located outside of the main folder

Tags: django

In my main template folder I have 2 folders
explorer and includes

```
template 
  explorer
     body.html
  includes
     header.html
```

I want to include in my body.html file  header.html from includes folder

tried those options :

```
{% include "../includes/header.html" with active_tab='dashboard' %}
{% include "/includes/header.html" with active_tab='dashboard' %}
```

in both options - can not find the path

What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django template paths are always absolute, from the root of the template folder (or whatever folder is included in the TEMPLATE dirs setting.) So it's just `{% include 'includes/header.html' %}`.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. You should show the full error message, and the actual file directory layout.

Comment: Sorry deleted  previous comment.

Comment: You answered my question . Thank you . Actually I came to different problem that was hidden under this one and this is what confused me originally. The include is not giving the error but is not displaying menu , maybe it is bootstrap related will play with tags.